# Php array explode a char

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "Family Deluxe for 4 Person x 1"
  1 => "Studio Deluxe for 2 Person x 1"
  2 => "Additional Adult x 2"
  3 => "Additional Children x 2"
]
```

When I pass into a `foreach` loop to remove the `x` and get the count, I encounter the following output result:

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "Family Delu" => "e for 4 Person "
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "Studio Delu" => "e for 2 Person "
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    " Additional Adult " => " 2"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    " Additional Children" => " 2"
  ]
]
```

The issues is, there is `x` char in the string `Deluxe` so the loop getting confuse on where to start an `explode()`. Following were my code for `foreach`:

```
foreach($a as $s) {
            list($size, $quantity) = explode('x', $s);
            $data[] = array($size => $quantity);
            $sumVariant += $quantity;
        }
```

How can I get `explode()` to recognize the `x` with spaces on both side? Thanks!!

Comment: Put spaces around it: `explode(' x ', $s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter argument to `explode()` doesn't have to be a single character, it can be any string. So use `x` with spaces around it as the delimiter.

```
list($size, $quantity) = explode(' x ', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode(" x ", $s);` should do the trick. Or you could get the last item of the explode array.